# Can't get batch to remove a weird double quote character from a string

Tags: batch-file

In our company, they export their SAP data into a text file. Sometimes the users from SAP type in the double quote character as ” and not a ". When it gets exported, it is shown weird in notepad++ and when the batch echos it. I would like to remove this character when I'm running my batch file for analysis. However, I don't know how to do this.

You can find a sample text file here: 
https://1drv.ms/t/s!At4HWeqiFYNvh-d-1vpV9cLWvsXQug

The code I am using is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set FileLocation=C:\desktop\test.txt
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('findstr /I "ABC" %FileLocation%%') DO (
    Set FileLine=%%a
    echo !FileLine!
    Set RemoveChar=!FileLine:”=!
    Set RemoveChar=!RemoveChar:ö=!
    Echo !RemoveChar!
)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have to enable delayed expansion. https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Comment: I looked back at your previous batch file questions and the answers to some of them show delayed expansion being enabled.

Comment: Sorry... I forgot to add the header code. I do have enabledelayedexpansion. I edited the original post. I think the issue has to do with the character being used.

Comment: can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: that's called smart quotes. And you need to use the correct encoding, otherwise the character might be invalid and replaced with `?`

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but I find a solution.

---

By changing the code page, it is possible for both Notepad++ and command prompt to process the text string properly.

First, save the batch file as UTF-8 encoding. It can be done by choosing "UTF-8" in the encoding menu.

Second, add `chcp 65001` to the beginning of the script. This allows command processor to see the characters as UTF-8.

---

Here is the fixed code:

```
@echo off

CHCP 65001

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set FileLocation=C:\desktop\test.txt
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('findstr /I "ABC" %FileLocation%%') DO (
    Set FileLine=%%a
    echo !FileLine!
    Set RemoveChar=!FileLine:”=!
    Set RemoveChar=!RemoveChar:ö=!
    Echo !RemoveChar!
)
```